# I need help with a result in the Berry Connection definition

Tags: quantum-mechanics, solid-state-physics, berry-pancharatnam-phase

I was reading B. Andrei Bernevig's "Topological Insulators and Topological Superconductors" and on the chapter simple model for Chern insulators there is a step where he states the Berry connection for dirac Fermions. (Last statement in the image.)

[image: B. Andrei Bernevig's "Topological Insulators and Topological Superconductors", Ch. 8. pg. 92]

I can't quite figure how he reached the result of eq. 8.5. When I tried it myself I am unable to see why there are so few terms left in the final expression since the derivative operator will operator on all terms of the matrix as well as on the terms outside the matrix and after the matrix multiplication it is getting very complicated. Can someone explain it to me how it can be simplified.

Comment: It takes a few lines of algebra, but the computation itself is straightforward. Many of the terms end up canceling. I'm not sure how to write an answer to this that isn't simply doing the calculation for you - I don't think there's a conceptual issue here.

Comment: @J.Murray Help me with this. Won't the differential operator also work on the term outside the matrix (the fraction)? That's what confusing me because after taking the derivative I am getting a lot of terms which I am unable to find way to cancel out even after the matrix multiplication.

Comment: Try working through the calculation and **show** what you have done in your OP. This will show whether you have a conceptual misunderstanding or simply made an algebraic error.

Answer (score 2):

Notice that if you have a normalized vector in $\mathbb C^2$
$$|\psi\rangle = \frac{1}{\sqrt{|A|^2+|B|^2}} \pmatrix{A\\B}$$
then
$$\langle \psi | \partial |\psi\rangle = \frac{1}{\sqrt{|A|^2+|B|^2}} \pmatrix{A^* & B^*} \left[\partial\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{|A|^2+|B|^2}}\right) \pmatrix{A\\B} + \frac{1}{\sqrt{|A|^2+|B|^2}} \pmatrix{\partial A\\\partial B}\right]$$

This can be simplified further, but it should be clear that this cleans up rather nicely. In particular, after a few more lines of algebra you should obtain
$$\langle \psi|\partial|\psi\rangle = \frac{\text{a few terms involving derivatives}}{|A|^2+|B|^2}$$

When in doubt, if the algebra seems like a horrendous mess you can always collect terms into things like $A$ and $B$ and see how far you get before you need to substitute (in this case, $A=d_3 \pm d$ and $B= d_1 - i d_2$).

Comment: Thanks man. I get it now.